# SQL query to get unique id having specific marks in specific subject

Tags: sql, mysql

Wanted to write a SQL query to get unique ids which has 80 marks in Maths and 70 Marks in English and Total Marks is >= 400. Ans would be id - 1 and 2.

```
ID      Subject Marks
1   Maths   80
1   English 70
1   Hindi   80
1   Science 80
1   SST 90
2   Maths   80
2   English 70
2   Hindi   90
2   Science 80
2   SST 100
3   Maths   80
3   English 60
3   Hindi   90
3   Science 100
3   SST 100
```

I am confused how I will insert both subjects as filter together.

Valid Query -

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `ff`
WHERE (`SUBJECT`='MATHS' AND `MARKS`= 80 AND `ID` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `ff` GROUP BY `ID` HAVING SUM(`MARKS`) >=400) ) OR (`SUBJECT`= 'ENGLISH' AND `MARKS`=70 AND  `ID` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `ff` GROUP BY `ID` HAVING SUM(`MARKS`) >=400) )
```

But this is not giving expected result.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT `ID` 
FROM `ff`
GROUP BY `ID` 
HAVING SUM(`MARKS`) >= 400  
  AND SUM(case when `SUBJECT` = 'English' then `MARKS`end) = 70 
  AND SUM(case when `SUBJECT` = 'Math' then `MARKS` end) = 80
```